# Python : Open chrome with parameters

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to open chrome with parameters but I figure how to do it.  Can anyone help me out?

I've listed the commands, one that works (without any parameters) and one that doesn't (with parameters):

```
call(["chromium-browser",""]) # this works 
call(["'chromium-browser --start-fullscreen'",""]) # this doesnt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subprocess.call` takes either a sequence of program arguments or a single string (with `shell=True`).

You should either do:

```
call(['chromium-browser', '--start-fullscreen'])
```

or:

```
call('chromium-browser --start-fullscreen', shell=True)
```

Please refer to [documentation of `Popen`'s constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for more details.